# Are leapseconds taken in account in dotNet (or C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time

Does the DateTime struct takes care of this? 
Does any other class/struct?

UPDATE :

I now have read that leapseconds are only announced 6 months in advance, since the rotation of the earth is not that predictable...

Since there's no possibility to implement that in future dates, I can imagine they just omitted them?

Comment: What do you mean by "take care of this"? In contrast to leap years where you have an additional day (29th February), the leap seconds are not so specific; they are just one second delays between two minutes, without this explicit distinction like the 29th February.

So basically you would expect or like a TimeSpan between to dates with a leap second in between to return the additional secons in the TotalSeconds property for instance?

Comment: indeed, and have times like the New DateTime(2008, 12, 2, 12, 34, 60)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to both your questions is No.
Reference: http://silverlight.net/forums/t/12114.aspx

Comment: Link doesn't provide the answer.

Comment: @David. That's because they removed that uri. It's 7 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, .NET's DateTime struct does NOT automatically handle leap seconds.  I don't think you can even set seconds higher than 59 in .NET's DateTime.  However, in Java, you are allowed to set seconds to be 0 - 61, because the ISO standard for it allows for 2 leap seconds per year.

**EDIT**: I Tried it for kicks:

Trying `Dim dt As New DateTime(2008, 12, 2, 12, 34, 61)` in .NET throws this message (61 being the number of seconds):

> "Hour, Minute, and Second parameters
>   describe an un-representable
>   DateTime."

Comment: A quick look at the implementation of DateTime in Reflector shows the logic in the private helper TimeToTicks: ((second < 0) || (second >= 60)) ... throw...

Answer (score 0):

No, not DateTime, since source code does not seem to have it.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs