# Are .Net's DateTime methods capable of recognising a Leap Second?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, utc

With a [Leap Second on the horizon for June this year](ftp://hpiers.obspm.fr/iers/bul/bulc/bulletinc.dat) it got me wondering whether the .Net framework is leap second aware? The extra second is to be inserted after the last second of June 30th so UTC will officially be:

```
2012 June 30,     23h 59m 59s
2012 June 30,     23h 59m 60s
2012 July  1,      0h  0m  0s
```

Is the .Net framework capable of handling this? Does it even matter if [Windows is not Leap Second aware](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909614)? Will this affect apps in mono running on O/S's that *are* Leap Second aware?

**EDIT:**

To expand on this a little bit i'm envisioning a scenario where a Java based solution on Linux (which is Leap Second aware) calls a .Net Web Service passing in something that is a valid timestamp in Java but is out of bounds for .Net. Are there any frameworks that cater for it (Like Noda Time perhaps)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781370/are-leapseconds-taken-in-account-in-dotnet-or-c

Comment: There is an updated question from 2019 involving Windows 10's new capability of actually handling leap seconds. But not really. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55964042/with-the-win-10-oct-2018-update-windows-is-leap-second-aware-is-nets-datetim

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No -

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.
>
> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001, which represents DateTime.MinValue. **It does not include the number of ticks that are attributable to leap seconds.**

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx

Comment: Which moves the issue to "what happens when the system clock gets recalibrated on the *next* NTP update?"

Comment: @Hans Passant: Interesting question. What happened to the clocks last time, in December 31, 2008?

Answer (score 12):

The .Net DateTime has no provisions for Leap Seconds, but will simply rely on the OS time. Windows is blissfully unaware of Leap Seconds<sup>[(1)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909614)[(2)](http://www.meinberg.de/english/info/leap-second.htm)</sup>, and so will just have the notion of time as it receives it from its NTP master (I believe the default for a non-domain connected machine is [time.windows.com](http://time.windows.com)), which is probably serving up UTC including leap seconds.

See also my answer to "[Calculating Future Epoch Time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906034/calculating-future-epoch-time-in-c-sharp/906326)" which goes into more details.

1. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909614
2. http://www.meinberg.de/english/info/leap-second.htm