# Does DateTime include second leap function?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

In this article: [Are .Net's DateTime methods capable of recognising a Leap Second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760674/are-nets-datetime-methods-capable-of-recognising-a-leap-second), the writer gets the answer "It (DateTime) does not include the number of ticks that are attributable to leap seconds."

However, the following code shows that .Net DateTime supports leap seconds. Could any expert explain why?

```
Dim GPS_Time_Base_Point As DateTime = New DateTime(1980, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
Dim A_test_time As DateTime = New DateTime(2019, 4, 16, 18, 29, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)

Dim TimeSpan As TimeSpan = A_test_time - GPS_Time_Base_Point
Dim GPS_Time_At_LIGO_for_2019_4_16_18_29_0 As UInt64 = 1239474558 'https://www.andrews.edu/~tzs/timeconv/timeconvert.php
Dim DifSeconds As Integer = TimeSpan.TotalSeconds - 1239474558
Debug.Print(" Second dif:" + CDbl(DifSeconds).ToString)
```

The output is "Second dif:-18", which is just equal to the leap second dif for gpstime - UTC time.

Comment: Second dif:-18 ,It just equal leap second dif for gpstime - utc time .

Comment: `DateTime` is a structure, not a class.